# While loop always returns false trying to confirm ending of a string

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a function that confirms an end of a string,
given a certain string ("Bastian") and a char ("n") it returns false/true based on the last char on the supplied string.
In this example, it should return `true`.

For some reason, it always returns `false`.

I have tried setting i is greater than -1 and it did not work

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  let i = str.length - 1;
  while (i >= 0) {
    if (str.substring(i, i - 1) != target.substring(i, i - 1)) {
      return false
    }
    i--;
  }
  return true;
}

confirmEnding("Bastian", "n");
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Well the `return true` doesn't run because the `return false` was executed during the loop, ending execution of the function… [Use a debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/) (or just `console.log` calls) to inspect the values of `i`, `str.substring(i, i - 1)` and `target.substring(i, i -1)` during the loop to find your mistake.

Comment: (Assuming this is an exercise, otherwise you should use [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith): `"Bastian".endsWith("n")` returns `true`)

Comment: can confirm @Bergi here: using a return false inside a loop will break out from the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison

```
str.substring(i, i - 1) != target.substring(i, i - 1)
```

is incorrect.
It is comparing substrings starting at index i and ending at index i - 1.
Which would always result in an **empty string**. Instead, we need to compare individual characters at each index using str[i] and target[i].

Try this:

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  let i = str.length - 1;
  let j = target.length - 1;

  while (j >= 0) {
    if (str[i] !== target[j]) {
      return false;
    }
    i--;
    j--;
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "n")); // Output: true
```

Comment: You'll also want to ensure that `i >= 0` by doing an early `return false` if `i < j` (i.e. when the string is shorter than the suffix)